# ReactJS: Why doesn't CSS Flexbox's alignItems work?

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, reactjs

In ReactJS, Using Material-UI's `<TextField/>` http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/text-field, I am trying to make all of the float to the left but be spaced out in between the two, but the alignItems isn't working. It just floats to the left and not spaced out in between.

What may be the issue?

```
render() {

    return ( 
        <div style={{display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'row wrap', alignItems: 'stretch'}}>
          <div>
            <TextField/>
          </div>
          <div>
            <TextField/>
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the correct property. In a row context, you should use `justify-content` to place elements on the x-axis.

```
render() {
  return ( 
    <div style={{display: 'flex', flexFlow: 'row wrap', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
      <div>
        <TextField/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <TextField/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```